# Create a shapefile from a python list using ArcPy?

Tags: python-2.7, gis, arcgis, esri, arcpy

I've been looking for a way to create a shapefile from a python list (in the case below, uniqueList).

Basically, I have been using SearchCursor's to iterate through a shapefile, and I would like to export the result as a shapefile...I tried CopyFeatures...but it didn't even return a blank file (it returned nothing).

```
import arcpy

def find_overlaps(input_features, output_features):
   uniqueList = []
   for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_features, ('OBJECTID', 'SHAPE@', 'name')):
      foundMatch = False
      for row2 in uniqueList:
          if row[1].equals(row2[1]):
              foundMatch = True
              break
      if foundMatch == False
          uniqueList.append(row)
   return uniqueList
   ## no work ##
   arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(uniqueList, output_features)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create the feature class first. Use arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_managment(). In this function you can use template feature to specify fields. You can use your inputp_features and if you want only selected fields, you can use arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (), should work. Alternatively you can create feature class without fields and then use arcpy.AddField_management() to add desired fields. For exact syntax check help there are few useful examples.

Good luck.